# Documentation for JavaScript Event Hanlders

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a list of all JavaScript event handlers (such as onLoad, onSubmit ect...) and the corresponding html tags that they can be applied to.  [This](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/handlers.htm) is is the best document I have found so far,  but I believe it is is incomplete. The [W3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3) are even worse,  all it says is `"This attribute may be used with most elements."`.   All browsers have their own quarks,  if you know of a document for a specific browser like Firefox or IE that would also be helpful.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of javascript, consider using one of the established frameworks, as it takes a lot of the cross-browser concerns out of the picture and will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) and [Quirksmode event compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)

[Here's](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) a nice tutorial too.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on quirksmode.org: http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html